# Lower bound of determinant of a Gram matrix given its main diagonal elements

Tags: linear-algebra

I encounter with this question where I want to find a positive lower bound of the determinant of a complex Gram matrix, say $\Omega$ with size $P \times P$. However, all I know is the main diagonal elements, $\Omega$ is a positive definite Hermitian matrix, i.e., the corrsponding vectors are indenpendent, and $\Omega$ is a diagonally dominant matrix. Also finding the eigenvalues of $\Omega$ is quite difficult. Is there something that may help me with this question? Thank you.

Comment: No.  The diagonal of your matrix is majorized by the eigenvalues of said matrix.  The determinant is a schur concave function, so what you are asking for is impossible... if you know what the diagonal of the inverse matrix is (precision matrix) you could do something with that...

Comment: If the vectors are linearly dependent then the determinant is 0. Do know anything about the vectors?

Comment: Thank you for your kind comments. Unfortunately I do not have much information about the inverse matrix or the exact values of the vectors. But I do know that this matrix is diagonally dominant. I hope its helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless $\Omega$ is $1\times1$, there isn't any positive lower bound, because the infimum is zero. In fact, given any $\omega_{11},\omega_{22},\ldots,\omega_{nn}>0$, if we pick some $\epsilon\in(0,\sqrt{\omega_{11}})$ and define
$$
X=\pmatrix{\epsilon&\sqrt{\omega_{11}-\epsilon^2}\\ 0&\sqrt{\omega_{22}}}\oplus\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{\omega_{33}},\ldots,\sqrt{\omega_{nn}}),
$$
then the Gram matrix $\Omega=XX^T$ is nonsingular and its diagonal is equal to $(\omega_{11},\omega_{22},\ldots,\omega_{nn})$, but $\det\Omega=(\det X)^2=\epsilon^2\prod_{j=2}^n\omega_{jj}$ can be arbitrarily close to zero.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think your explanation indeed makes sense.

Comment: @user1551 I like your short answer. I have just provided another one with a special matrix that may interest you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach.

Let $a$ and $b$ be two parameters with

$$0<a<b\tag{1}$$

Consider

$$X=\begin{pmatrix}a& 0& 0& 0& 0& b\\
 b& a& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 0& b& a& 0& 0& 0\\
  0& 0& b& a& 0& 0\\
  0& 0& 0& b& a& 0\\
  0& 0& 0& 0& b& a \end{pmatrix}$$

with structure

$$X=aI_6+bC_6\tag{2}$$

where $C_6$ is a circulant matrix.

One can easily prove that

$$\det(X)=a^6-b^6$$

The Gram matrix associated with $X$ is

$$G=X^TX=(aI+bC^T)(aI+bC)=a^{2}I+ab(C+C^T)+b^2\underbrace{CC^T}_{I}$$

i.e.,

$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
  a^2 + b^2&       ab&         0&         0&         0&       ab\\
        ab& a^2 + b^2&       ab&         0&         0&         0\\
          0&       ab& a^2 + b^2&       ab&         0&         0\\
          0&         0&       ab& a^2 + b^2&       ab&         0\\
          0&         0&         0&       ab& a^2 + b^2&       ab\\
        ab&         0&         0&         0&       ab& a^2 + b^2\end{pmatrix}$$

$G$ is strictly diagonally dominant (indeed $a^2+b^2 > 2ab$) with

$$\det(G)=(a^6-b^6)^2 > 0$$

proving that $G$ is positive definite.

This determinant can be made arbitrarily small ; therefore, the smallest eigenvalue of $G$ can itself be made arbitrarily small. One can exhibit the smallest eigenvalue ; in fact, the spectrum of $G$ can be sorted in the general case in this way :

$$ \underbrace{(a - b)^2}_{\text{smallest eigenvalue}} \ < \ a^2 - ab + b^2 \ < \ a^2 + ab + b^2 \ < \ (a + b)^2 \tag{3} $$

(the two central eigenvalues being with multiplicity 2).

**Remark** :

We have chosen here to work with a $6 \times 6$ matrix for didactic reasons, but the results just shown can be extended in a straightforward manner to a $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix with the same structure (see (2)). In this general case, we still continue to deal with eigenvalues of a circulant matrix, which are in the general case :

$$\lambda_k=a^2+b^2+2ab \cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right) \ \ \ \ (k=0,1,\cdots n)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is smart and very detailed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, as indicated in the other answers, there is no general lower bound. But maybe the following is useful:

Call $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $G$ with smallest absolute value. If $G$ is the Gram matrix of some tuple $(e_1, \ldots, e_n)$, then
$$|\lambda| = \min_{(c_i) \in \mathbb C^n - \{0\}} \frac{\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n c_i e_i \right \Vert}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |c_i|^2}} \,.$$
So if somehow you are in a situation where you can bound the norms $\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n c_i e_i \right \Vert$ from below (think of this as bounding the distance from the origin to an ellipsoid) then you can bound $\det(G)$ from below.